# Getting index out of bounds error trying to make a method that adds an int to an array in java

Tags: java, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception

Doing some school stuff and I basically need to create a Method that "pushes" an integer to an array at the last position (basically recreating the Stack.push() method).

```
public class IntegerStack {
    
    int[] storage;
    int height;

    public IntegerStack(int i) {
        this.storage = new int[i];
        this.height = 0;
    }
    
    public void push(int i) {
        if(height == 0) {
            storage[height] = i;
            height++;
        } else {

            int[] tempArr = new int[storage.length + 1];
            
            for(int j = 0; j < storage.length - 1 ; j++) {
                tempArr[j] = storage[j];
            }
                tempArr[tempArr.length] = i;
                storage = tempArr;
                height++;

            
        }
    }
```

I tried to create a Temporary array that has the same stuff as the original one + add the integer from the method at last position and then replace the original one with the temporary one, but I keep getting this error and I'm really stuck so I need some help

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 4 out of bounds for length 4
```

Comment: `tempArr[tempArr.length]` this will always give an index out of bounds exception, did you forget `- 1`?

Comment: side note: you don't need to check if `height == 0`. `push()` implementation just needs to be `storage[height++] = i;` and that's all. What happens `if height >= storage.length` (and you would need to grow storage) is up to you.

Comment: Could you use Arrays.copyOf with the new dimension?